# I want to show data in tables when ajax is called in php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I want to show only those data. which is selected in the dropdown list.

```
<select name="select" id="select">
      <?php
       $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","select");
       $query = mysqli_query($conn,"select * from users");
       while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
       ?>
       <option value="<?= $row['id'];?>"><?php echo $row['first_name'];?></option>
       <?php } ?>
   </select>
```

And then I want to only selected data from the dropdown in that table.

```
<table border="1">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>FirstName</th>
                <th>LastName</th>
                <th>Jobtitle</th>
                <th>DOB</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="data" >

        </tbody>
    </table>
```

This is the ajax code. but I don't know what can I write in the `success: function()` to show the data in tabular form.

```
<script>
$('#select').change(function(){
    var LocateId = $('#select').val();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'getSelect1.php',
        type: 'post',
        data : {id: LocateId},
        success:function(data)
        {


        }
    });
});

</script>
```

And This is the `getSelect1.php` page. which fetch the data from the database and returns it `JSON` format.

```
<?php
 $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","select");
$id = $_POST['id'];
 $query = "select * from users where id = '$id'";
        $cm = mysqli_query($conn,$query);

       $data = array();
    while( $rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($cm) ) {
        $data[] = $rows;
    }
    echo json_encode($data);


?>
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to append html data like below:

```
<script>
    $('#select').change(function() {
        var LocateId = $('#select').val();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'getSelect1.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: {
                id: LocateId
            },
            success: function(data) {
                $("#data").html("");
                $.each(data, function(k, v) {
                    if (v.state_id == $("state").val()) {
                        $("#data").append(`<tr>
                       <td>` + data.name + `</td>
            <td>` + data.name + `</td>
            <td>` + data.name + `</td>
            <td>` + data.name + `</td>
                    </tr>`);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

make sure you need to pass **state_id** column in you ajax response to match with state drop down id.

Please make sure before adding question on stack, you are clear on your question.

Comment: I have edited the question. please observe the question and then answer me the right solution. Thanks